# Vectorizing a weighted sum of matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, sum, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following operation in MATLAB, but it's got me stumped. I've learned from experience that there usually *is* a way, so I'm not giving up just yet. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a collection of `m` row-vectors each of size `n`, arranged in an *m* x *n* matrix; call it `X`.

I also have an m-sized vector of weights, *w*.

I want to compute a weighted sum of the matrices formed by the self outer products of the vectors in `X`.

Here is a MWE using a `for` loop:

```
m = 100;
n = 5;

X = rand(m, n);
w = rand(1, m);

S = zeros(n, n);
for i = 1 : m
    S = S + (w(i) * X(i, :)' * X(i, :));
end

S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the fastest approach:

```
S = X' * bsxfun(@times, X, w(:));
```

You could also do

```
S = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, ...
    bsxfun(@times, conj(X), permute(X, [1 3 2])), w(:)), 1));
```

(or remove the complex conjugate if not needed).

Comment: I saw your answer and I had the feeling that matrix multiplication could be exploited to a greater extent :-)

Comment: And it worked! It's great to motivate/"push" each other for better solutions ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can employ two approaches here that use one **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** call and few **[`permutes`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)** and **[`reshapes`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)**. The reshaping trick basically allows us to use the efficient `matrix multiplication` and thus avoid any extra `bsxfun` call we might have required otherwise.

### Approach #1

```
[m1,n1] = size(X);
XXmult = bsxfun(@times,X,permute(X,[1 3 2])); %// For X(i, :)' * X(i, :) step
S = reshape(reshape(permute(XXmult,[2 3 1]),[],m1)*w(:),n1,[]) %// multiply weights w
```

### Approach #2

```
[m1,n1] = size(X);
XXmult = bsxfun(@times,permute(X,[2 3 1]),permute(X,[3 2 1]));
S = reshape(reshape(XXmult,[],m1)*w(:),n1,[])
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest answer, and probably fastest:

S = X'*diag(W)*X

Been using it for an unscented Kalman filter, works great.